# Creating idiomatic and efficient method to stream large JSON file

Tags: f#

The purpose of the code is to efficiently stream JSON items from a large file.
I am wondering if this is efficient and decently idiomatic. Not sure how I could eliminate the while loop either.

```
module Seq =
    let inline tryMove (e:IEnumerator<'T>) =
        try
            let moved = e.MoveNext()
            if moved then
                Some <| Choice1Of2 e.Current
            else
                e.Dispose()
                None
        with ex ->
            Some <| Choice2Of2 ex
    let catch (items:_ seq) =
        use e = items.GetEnumerator()
        e
        |> Seq.unfold(
            tryMove
            >> function
            | Some (Choice1Of2 item) -> Some(Choice1Of2 item,e)
            | Some (Choice2Of2 ex) -> Some(Choice2Of2 ex, e)
            | None -> None
        )


module SuperSerial =
    let deserialize<'T>(x):'T =
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'T>(x)

    let streamJson<'T> sr =
        let serializer = JsonSerializer()
        seq{
            use r = new JsonTextReader(sr)
            while r.Read() do
                if r.TokenType = JsonToken.StartObject then
                    yield serializer.Deserialize<'T>(r)
        }
    let streamString<'T> x =
        seq{
            use s = new StringReader(x)
            yield! streamJson(s)
        }
    let streamJsonFile<'T> target =
        seq{
            use s = File.Open(target,FileMode.Open)
            use sr = new StreamReader(s)
            yield! streamJson(sr)
        }
```